# How to Reobtain Year 1 Weapons

Tags: destiny

I'm a Day 1 player in Destiny, so I've been there for all of the events and DLC drops. Because of this, I've gotten some sweet loot in the past year and a half. When The Taken King dropped, I had to clear some space in my vault and delete my Y1 guns (shortly after, Bungie announced they were doubling the vault space, so *perfect* timing). One particular gun I scrapped was the [Y-09 Longbow Synthesis](http://destinydb.com/items/935317314-y-09-longbow-synthesis), a beautiful Legendary sniper with an impact that rivals the 1000-Yard Stare, with a god roll. Is there any way I can get any Year 1 weapons back? I've tried running Legacy Strikes, but I've only gotten rare Y2 gear. I've even tried lowering my Light level to sub-170, but still no luck.

**TL;DR:** Accidentally dismantled some Year 1 Legendary weapons, don't know how to/if I can reobtain them

Comment: Now that the April update is out, you are able to get some of the year 1 legendary weapons from vanguard/crucible rank up packages, including the longbow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some legendarys were tied to events like the queens ransom or original iron banner and are unobtainable. Before 2.0 and the Taken King you used to be able to get legendary engrams from lower level strikes (not during the strike itself but in the end mission screen) and those would decrypt into older legendarys. Though those older strikes were done away with and replaced with the single legacy playlist in the 2.0 update.

So no, aside from gear in the older Raids and Prison of Elders since that is tied to still existing activities, you won't be able to reobtain year one equipment.

Comment: Damn, that's upsetting haha. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I've done some digging on Reddit and saw that you can possibly get Year 1 gear from the level 28 Prison of Elders arena. Have you heard of anything like this being true?

Comment: I hadn't thought about the Prison. I'm sure you could still pick up at least weapons from the queen's arsenal, but other than that I'm unsure what would be included.

Answer (score 1):

I got a high road soldier from end screen and some people have got hopscotch pilgrim and you can also get year 1 legendary engrams

Answer (score 0):

save engrams delete the taken king open them and re-download the king

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to accomplish? In order to connect to Destiny servers, you'll still be on the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

you can farm for year 1 legendary weapons and sometimes engrams from year 1 prison of elders.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching this topic and heard that you can still get year one blues like hard luck mk. 52, Pompeii, etc... (which are actually more rare than exotics) by decrypting engrams on a level 16 or lower character. Which means you have to delete one if you already have 3... but if that's not a problem for you, it's worth a try. A lot of year one blues actually outperform a lot of legendary and exotic weapons in the crucible. Or if you're just a collector. Worth a try I suppose. The guns I mentioned above are reeeeeeallllly good. Also, if you do decide to delete your character and you reobtain the shotgun "lockjaw", keep it. It's amazing In the crucible and as far as I know, you can only obtain it once.